# Share code between controllers and directives

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app I have two input fields on most views that have a start and end date. These are updated by the user and the result is stored in the URL to maintain state or allow people to share links and start exactly where they left off.

I am trying to extract this into a directive that updates the url on every change to one of those two fields. Additionally I want each controller to be able to access the dates as they are used as query parameters for other endpoints.

Here is my directive:

```
angular
.module('dateDemo')
.directive('DateFields',['$location', DateFields]);

function DateFields($location) {

return {
  templateUrl: 'shared/partials/_dateFields.html',
  scope: false,
  bindToController: {
    start_date  :   '=',
    end_date    :   '='
  },
  controller: DateFieldCtrl,
  controllerAs: 'dateCtrl'
};

function DateFieldCtrl() {
    var dateCtrl          = this;
    dateCtrl.refreshUrl   = refreshUrl;

    function refreshUrl() {
        var searchString    = '';
        searchString += '&start_dt=' + moment(dateCtrl.start_dt).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        searchString += '&end_dt=' + moment(dateCtrl.end_dt).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $location.search(searchString);
    }
}
}
```

My Partial:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> <b>Date</b></label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.data.start_dt" ng-change="refreshURL()">
    <p class="text-right"><small class="help-block">From Date</small></p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.data.end_dt" ng-change="refreshURL()">
    <p class="text-right"><small class="help-block">To Date</small></p>
</div>
```

What I'm attempting to do is bind the `vm.data.end_dt` and `vm.data.start_dt` variables so that the directive manages the updating, while the controllers have access to these values. I can't get the function in my directive to trigger, and I've tried different combinations of which variable goes in the partial to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `controllerAs: 'dateCtrl'`, you need to change your ng-change code to call `dateCtrl.refreshUrl()`

Also, you have `vm.data` referenced in your ng-model, which I think should also be `dateCtrl`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> <b>Date</b></label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="dateCtrl.start_dt" ng-change="dateCtrl.refreshURL()">
    <p class="text-right"><small class="help-block">From Date</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="dateCtrl.end_dt" ng-change="dateCtrl.refreshURL()">
    <p class="text-right"><small class="help-block">To Date</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions and it didn't work. When I use `ng-model="vm.data.start_dt"` in the directive template I get the date filled in. Is there anything else I am messing up?

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you could provide a working example, like on jsFiddle. Do you think you could put one together and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by including `bindToController: true`.